# Command run via xargs fails but runs manually

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm trying to create a command that will automatically attach to my existing python docker container, and trying to chain a bunch of commands together.

```
docker ps | grep "mypythoncontainer" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker attach
```

If I run

```
docker ps | grep "mypythoncontainer" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs echo
```

I get back a docker id string, as expected. And if I do `docker attach {id string}` (copied from the return of the statement right above this), it works. But when I run the full command at top, I get an error (`the input device is not a TTY`).

So `docker ps | grep "mypythoncontainer" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs echo` would echo out `abc`, but `docker ps | grep "mypythoncontainer" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker attach` would fail, while `docker attach abc` works. Not sure what about xargs I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
docker attach $(docker ps | grep "mypythoncontainer" | awk '{print $1}')
```

or simplier:

```
docker attach $(docker ps | awk '/mypythoncontainer/{print $1}')
```

> Not sure what about xargs I don't understand.

Running: `...| ... docker ...` will redirect `docker`'s *standard input* to ... the ouput of `awk`, wich was already read by `xargs`. So `docker abc` will  r
un with a broken (already closed) *`STDIN`*, then fail.